# Error when using two components that rely on the same Context

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have a SearchBar component that has 'Places' component that uses the 'Posctode' and 'FilterOption' component that uses the 'price', 'bedroomCount', others from the SearchInputContext. I am getting the error below

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
    at FilterOption (FilterOption.js:8:1)
```

Which I believe is because both Places and FilterOption is using the same context i.e. SearchInputContext. Now I can easily solve this by creating a separate context for FilterOption for eg. FilterOptionContext.

My question is, that is there a more simple way to do this or do we have to create a separate Context everytime we need a new set of share data between multiple component?

```
const SearchBar = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Places />
            <FilterOption />        
        </>
    )
}
```

```
const Places = () => {
  const {postCode, setPostCode } = useContext(SearchInputContext); 
}
```

```
const FilterOption = () => {
    const[price, setPrice, bedroomCount, setBedroomCount, bathroomCount, setBathroomCount, parkingCount, setParkingCount]
     = useContext(SearchInputContext);
}
```

```
const SearchInputContext = createContext({});

export const SearchInputProvider = ({ children}) => {
    const [postCode, setPostCode] = useState();
    const [price, setPrice] = useState();
    const [bedroomCount, setBedroomCount] = useState();
    const [bathroomCount, setBathroomCount] = useState();
    const [parkingCount, setParkingCount] = useState();
       
    return (
        <SearchInputContext.Provider value={{
            postCode, setPostCode, price, setPrice, bedroomCount, setBedroomCount, bathroomCount, setBathroomCount, 
            parkingCount, setParkingCount, 
        }}>
            {children}
        </SearchInputContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the FilterOption component, the return value of useContext is an object, but you are destructuring it into an array.
You must use object destructuring.

```
const {price, setPrice, bedroomCount, setBedroomCount, bathroomCount, setBathroomCount, parkingCount, setParkingCount}
 = useContext(SearchInputContext);
```

Comment: My bad. Thanks!